# Rename Many Files in a Folder - PHP

Tags: php, renaming

I have 2500 images in a Folder, which has NAME word in all the images. For examples

```
Peter Wang B5357550.jpg
Sander Mackiney B5355624.jpg
```

what i need to do is read all the filenames and rename it to the following

```
B5357550.jpg
B5355624.jpg
```

So remove NAME and SURNAME from filename, is it possible in PHP to do bulk renaming ?
(All student IDs are in format of Bxxxxxxx)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do bulk renaming in PHP. Is there anything you have tried that we can help with?

Comment: On Linux you may consider `rename` command to bulk rename files. You can find some examples at http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 2):

Quick, simple solution:

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/your-folder-to-files';
$files = scandir($dir);
unset($files[0],$files[1]);
foreach ($files as $oldname){
    $newname = substr($oldname, -12);
    rename ($dir.'/'.$oldname, $dir.'/'.$newname);
}
```

---

**N.B.:** You may need to change the server path to something similar to:

```
$dir = "/home/users/you/folder_files/";
```

or

```
$dir = "folder_files/";
```

- If `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does not work for you.

Answer (score -1):

If they're all in that format, it would be simple to fix, yes. Run `glob` to get all the .jpg files into an array, then simply `explode` the filename on spaces, use a `foreach` loop on that array, use `end` to get the last section, and `rename` the file to that string.